# Create dropdown box based on database query?

Tags: java, jsp

So I am creating an online bank transfer section where the user can transfer money between their account. I have a drop down box where it will show the amount of accounts the user has. I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. Here is my code so far:

transfer-page.jsp

```
 <form name="transfer" action="TransferServlet" method="post">
            <% 
                String email = (String) session.getAttribute("email");
                String getAccountType = UserProfileService.getAccountTypeByEmail(email);
                int count = UserProfileService.getAmountOfAccounts(email);
             %>
            From Account: <select name="AccountType">

                                    <%
                                        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                                        {
                                    %>
                                           <option>  <%=getAccountType %>
                                           <%
                                        }
                                    %> 
                                           </option>
                          </select>
        </form>
```

Database Class:

```
 public static String getAccountTypeByEmail(String email)
        {
          //  AccountType accountType = new AccountType();
            String getAccountType = "";
            try
            {
                Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
                String query = "SELECT * FROM accountType WHERE email=?";
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                stmt.setString(1, email);

                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                rs.next();

                getAccountType = rs.getString("accountType");

              //  accountType.setAccountType(getAccountType);

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

          //  return accountType;
          return getAccountType;
        }

        public static int getAmountOfAccounts(String email)
        {
            int count = 0;
            try
            {
                Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
                String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM accountType WHERE email=?";
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                stmt.setString(1, email); 

                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while(rs.next())
                {
                   String account = rs.getString("accountType");
                   count++;
                }

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            return count;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know under what circumstances you will appear in the drop-down box shows the amount of the account. An account binding more than one bank card?
String getAccountType = UserProfileService.getAccountTypeByEmail(email); your method getAccountTypeByEmail(String email) return only one result,why you loop show it.